# Get Flex modules from ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, module, load

We´re developing an ASP MVC application witch the View (aspx) has a Flex embed. This aspx/flex view is composed by a flex application and several modules.

So, when we call the application url (*http://localhost:9090/MyProject/Flex/Index*), the server invoke the method the will return the ActionResult that represents this action, in this case the *~/Views/Flex/Index.aspx* (with the Flex app). **However when the ModuleLoader, in the Flex application, try to load a module an error occurs.** The problem is that the Flex application can´t directly access the modules folder (*~/Views/Flex/modules/module.swf*).

**Are there any way to get the module through an ASP MVC action? Or the best approach is to allow the access to this folder through web.config?**

Again, sorry for the poor english!

Thanks,
André

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views folder should be used for aspx/ascx views.  You'll want to put .swf files in in a content folder like ~/Content/modules/module.swf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Another question, the output folder in flash builder 4 is configure to View/Flex  folder. Can I configure it to build in different folders? Something like: build application into "View/Flex" and modules into "Content/Modules"?

Comment: @André Schuster  -  I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with FLEX/Flash, just ASP.NET MVC.  You may want to ask a separate question for this so it doesn't get lost in the comments.